how to encapsulate plotly graph in a function in R
I would like to encapsulate a plotly graph in a function, the way I do in ggplot :
testGraphggplot <- function(data,x,y){
ggplot(data,aes(x={{x}},y={{y}}))+
geom_point()
}

testGraphggplot(cars,speed,dist)

If I try this in plotly :
testGraphPlotly <- function(data,x,y){
plot_ly(data,x= ~{{x}},y=~{{y}}) %>% 
add_markers() %>% 
return()
}


testGraphPlotly(cars,speed,dist)

I get an error "object 'speed' not found"
I tried to put ~ before x and y, but nothing change.

You could use the ~ in your own custom function to create a custom function with plotly like this:
library(plotly)

testGraphPlotly <- function(data,x,y){
  plot_ly(data,x= x,y=y) %>% 
    add_markers() %>% 
    return()
}


testGraphPlotly(cars,~speed,~dist)


Created on 2024-04-04 with reprex v2.0.2

Thanks ! it's great, however I would rather like another solution : I want to have a single function with graph parameters (x, y, color...) and graph type parameter (plotly or ggplot), so that the same function can return either a plotly or a ggplot graph, with the same signature.

Tidy evaluation in functions (embracing via {{...}}) is made available for tidyverse-packages. Other packages, like plotly, treat the function arguments as actual objects (speed and dist, in your case), which aren't present in the current enviroment.
If you want to use tidy evaluation, you can do it the following way:
testGraphggplotly <- function(data, x, y) {
plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(data, aes(x = {{ x }}, y = {{ y }})) +
        geom_point()
ggplotly(plot)
}

testGraphggplotly(cars, speed, dist)

